# AngularJS detect end of input from http.get()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a PHP script that outputs data from a database. Sample would be:

```
[ {"id" : "1","name" : "myName1","thumb_width" : "360"}, 
  {"id" : "2","name" : "myName2","thumb_width" : "360"}]
```

Or something similar. I'm reading in quite a few records.  Problem is Angular is reacting when it gets too few.  I'm lazy loading these images.  As it were, it reads in one row, displays it, then thinks it's the last so disables the lazy loading, then I get more. :-/

I can put in some tacky entry into the output, but is there a more elegant solution that's native to get?

It works somewhat like this:

```
function imagesController($scope,$http) {
    $http.get( site + page )
    .success(function(response) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {

            // parse responses

        }
    }

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        // Figure out how much to load here
        // if we're at the end, disable lazy loading.
    }

};
```

See it in action here
http://onfilm.us/scroll3.html

EDIT: *OR* shouldn't loadMore() (which is being called once the rest of response is parsed) display the consecutive rows?  If you leave your console open you should be able to see it say it has 2 rows loaded, but only one visible.  At least here. :)